# How are these two invocations different?

Tags: c#, winforms, targetinvocationexception

I'm trying to modify a combo box on my WinForms application, and I'm getting some strange behavior. I'm trying two methods:

Here is the method I need to invoke:

```
private void modifyCombo(ClassInfoHolder oldClass, ClassInfoHolder newClass) {
    this.monitoredComboBox.Items[monitoredComboBox.Items.IndexOf(oldClass)] = newClass;
}
```

I'm trying two different ways to invoke this method from the GUI thread. This one works:

```
delegate void modifyComboCollection(ClassInfoHolder oldClass, ClassInfoHolder newClass);

private void modifySecondTabComboBox(ClassInfoHolder oldClass, ClassInfoHolder newClass) {
    if (monitoredComboBox.InvokeRequired) {
        modifyComboCollection m = new modifyComboCollection(modifyCombo);
        this.BeginInvoke(m, oldClass, newClass);
    } else {
        // no need for Invoke
        modifyCombo(oldClass, newClass);
    }
}
```

And this throws a TargetInvocationException:

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
    modifyCombo(oldClass, newClass);
}));
```

I'd prefer to use the second because it's much clearer, but I'm not entirely sure why it throws an error when the first example works just fine. The first example calls the `modifyCombo` method and correctly returns the `IndexOf` of the object. The second example is returned `-1` from `IndexOf`.

Edit: Here is a pastebin link of the stacktrace.
http://pastebin.com/TwfUDw4u

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace of the exception?  TargetInvocationException usually indicates that some exception was thrown elsewhere, and it was wrapped.  Knowing the real exception and where it happened will help debug.

Comment: @cdhowie Added; I'm a little baffled by it.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry about that, I just updated the link right before your post. The InnerException is that the `indexOf` method is returning `-1`, but I have no idea why because the combo box is populated and most definitely does have the `oldClass` object inside of it.

Comment: BeginInvoke with 3 arguments? I'm confused

Comment: The first argument is the method to call, second argument for BeginInvoke is `params object[] args`, for all the parameters the method takes

Comment: Maybe use a debugger to see why the IndexOutOfRangeException is being thrown?

Comment: oh nevermind, in my last comment I was iterating through and modifying the collection, which isn't a good idea. I fully understand why I get an error there. The problem in the main question still persists though -- I have NO idea why it is saying that my object does not exist in the collection when it does, and I'm not modifying the collection while iterating through it in any way... the two use cases are identical but one works while the other fails

Comment: Note about the Invoke() method (from MSDN): A call to an EventHandler or MethodInvoker delegate will be faster than a call to another type of delegate.

Comment: From that stack trace it sure seems like the problem is in the modifyCombo() method and not with the other stuff. Looks like you should be checking the index before using it.

Answer (score 0):

**this.BeginInvoke(m, new[] {oldClass, newClass});**

BTW. Good practice is to test if (this.IsHandleCreated && !this.IsDisposed) before use Invoke.

Comment: I've tried wrapping it in a `if (monitoredComboBox.InvokeRequired) { invoke } else { not invoke }` type block, with no luck.

Comment: And what? Are you sure that in first case monitoredComboBox.InvokeRequired returns true ? I'm talking about that

Comment: Yes, InvokeRequired returns true in both cases

Comment: `HandleCreated` and `Disposed` are EventHandlers, you can't use boolean logic on them

Comment: Sorry I'm writing from memory possibly IsHandleCreated and IsDisposed

Comment: Oh, sorry lol those are the right properties, but they are sadly not the cause of my problem